# Can undead be altered into another type of undead?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, undead, necromancy

I am playing a necromancer ([Cleric](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric)/[Wizard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard)/[Mystic Theurge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/mystic-theurge) with level 3 early entry cheese if you must know).

Let's say that I happen to have a dead body in front of me (don't ask where it came from or how it gained the "dead" status). At the time, it makes sense to make it into a zombie using [*animate dead*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animate-dead/) due to the abundance of flesh still clinging to its bones, otherwise ruining a perfectly good burning skeleton.

At some later point in time, I learn the spell [*decompose corpse*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/decompose-corpse/). Would this allow me to transform it into a skeleton? Basically, are there any ways of altering an existing undead into another type of undead, hopefully using low-level spells like the above or [*restore corpse*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/restore-corpse/)?

---

I have asked other questions about [restoring the materials of a destroyed undead for reuse](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/130468/23058), or [causing an undead to become dead without destroying it](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/143684/23058), or [if undead still count as corpses](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143687/do-undead-still-count-as-corpses), and all were answered "no".

Comment: I feel bad anwsering this when all the previous answers saying "no" are also mine.

Comment: @ShadowKras Its been here for over 12 hours, feel free to give me the answer I was expecting, even before your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Decompose Corpse doesn't do anything it doesn't say it does.

Decompose Corpse has a specific use against "non-skeletal undead" which is

> ...the creature takes a –2 penalty on all rolls and to its Armor Class and CMD for 1 minute.

### .... unless your GM is OK with it.

However, if you're not trying to do this in a combat, that could easily justify preparing a non-corpse to be Animated as a skeleton. They would of course be ignoring the RAW answer to [question you linked](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143687/do-undead-still-count-as-corpses).

Comment: I was hoping there was something I didnt know of that would basically allow me to get more use out of my undead since I cant seem to recycle them